# How to show that the locus of the centres of the spheres of a co-axial system is a straight line?

Tags: 3d, spheres

I proceeded like this, Let $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ be a point on the sphere $S_1$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ be the point satisfied by the sphere $S_2$ of a coaxial system.
Now I need to show that there exists straight line joining these two points.
 That is I need to prove $x_2-x_1$, $y_2-y_1$, $z_2-z_1$ not all zero. Is this right?. If wrong what how should I proceed.

Comment: Not clear what you need to do here.  Your spheres look like they are embedded in some 3-space (Euclidean?), and there, there exist straight lines between points that don't coincide. So the distance between the two points (the square root of the vector of differences you wrote down dotted with itself) non-zero is sufficient. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: you mean $\sqrt((x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2)$ must be non-zero.

Comment: or should I consider the determinant of $(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and the centers of the spheres and prove it will be equal to zero.But the centers are already co-linear.

Comment: In 3D Euclidean space, two points are joined by a straight line of non-zero length whenever they are not coincident.  So the distance being non-zero $\sqrt{((x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 + (z_2 + z_1)^2)} \neq 0$ is good enough. If there are no other constraints on the points.